# Process.Start(object) not working

Tags: c#, process.start

I am developing one application which creates PDF. I am using Process.Start(startInfo) to create PDF. Now when I run this application locally, it is working fine and creates PDF but when I deploy it on Development server it is not creating PDF.

I made it very simple to Process.Start("IExplore.exe"), however still it not working on Development server.

Please let me know if any other thing that I have to do it so start working?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: You might not have enough priveleges to start processes on the remote server.

Comment: Another "not working" question. We cannot read your mind, so please tell us what is or isn't happening and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably having this issue because on your local machine you're running under your account, which has permissions to run the executable. When deployed to the dev server, it's probably running under the NETWORK SERVICE account, which probably doesn't have permissions to run the executable. You need to look into using impersonation.

I gave a detailed answer on this here:

[Invoke or call C# console app from C# web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097071/invoke-or-call-c-console-app-from-c-web-service/7097928#7097928)