# Opening windows explorer via link

Tags: asp.net, html

I want to provide a means to open up Windows Explorer (or at least view the directory contents) via an internal webpage I've developed for our business.  There are several machines which we share over the internal network.  I've provided a text entry field for allow the user to enter the folder path they want to associate with a given row in a DB table and I can store that info off and create the `file://///10.10.5.10/Recipes/Pie` link to the Pie recipe folder on one of our shared machines.

The link renders correctly on the page and if I copy the link info and paste it into the address bar it will display a navigable page in FireFox or open Windows Explorer if using IE.

However, the link does nothing if you click on it directly on my page.  I suspect this might have something to do with security and the brower, right?  I've seen a SharePoint page in someone else's system that *did* work, but I'd guess that has to do with some differences between SharePoint and a webpage in a browser.  The work-around of right-clicking the link and copy/pasting it into another tab will work and I might have to live with this, but I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions or ways to deal with this issue.  Perhaps I'm just doing something wrong, but I'm pretty sure it's browser-security related.

Comment: can you provide a very simple (static html) example which reproduces the behaviour ? and which browser(s) ?

Comment: @Yahia, if I build a very simple html with just the link in it, double-click from explorer, it'll open in IE and when I click the link, it asks me to verify if I want to open Windows Explorer.  I don't get this behavior with the webpage I did in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: then this is definitely an issue of browser security... in which zone is your ASP.NET app ?

Comment: "Local intranet", if I'm answering the question I think you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried putting it client-/browser-side into "trusted sites" ?

Comment: @Yahia - didn't see how to do this in FireFox, assuming that I'm following you.

Comment: I was on IE... I will have to think more about FireFox then... btw: the answers below are all server-side and would only help IF you are accessing the UNC path from your app directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems for me as a pure Internet Explorer setting issue.

First of all I would recommend you better use UNC or DNS names in the path to the server instead of the usage of IP addresses: use `file://///myserver/Recipes/Pie` or `file://///myserver.mydomain.com/Recipes/Pie` instead of `file://///10.10.5.10/Recipes/Pie`.

Second you should better include the `file://///myserver`, `file://///myserver.mydomain.com` or even `file://///10.10.5.10/` to the "Local intranet" or at least to "Trusted sites" zone:

[image]

Then you should verify the setting of the Security Zone to which you map the url. Look at the "Miscellaneous" group for the "Display mixed contain":

[image]

If you would has "Prompt" setting you will see the warning:

[image]

at every attempt to open the link `file://///myserver/Recipes/Pie`

If you would has some problems I recommend you to reset the IE settings in "Advanced" tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's a permission issue.
ASP.net runs under the ASP.net process account.  Look for the ASPNET user and apply permissions to the folder for the user in question.

Comment: So this would be a "for each folder" action that I'd need to perform, right?

Answer (score 1):

It definitely sounds like a security issue. Try one or both of the following:

- Try using impersonation to impersonate a domain user with sufficient priveleges to access explorer on the client's machine
- If this is a small intranet application, give the application full trust on the client

Here's a link to a class you can use for impersonation - see my answer:

[Invoke or call C# console app from C# web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097071/invoke-or-call-c-console-app-from-c-web-service/7097928#7097928)

Comment: Thanks for the response James - I'll need to do some reading up on impersonation and how to do this.

Comment: I'll post a class for impersonating in the morning (almost 2am here).